# Не срабатывает триггер на проверку одинаковых значений в таблице

Tags: mysql, триггер

Есть таблица users. Нужно написать триггер, который проверяет, есть ли одинаковые логин и пароль в таблице. Если есть, то нужно выводить сообщение об ошибке. Но триггер не создается, вылетает сообщение о том, что невозможно выполнить триггер. Прошу помощи т.к я совсем новичок.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id_User` int(11) NOT NULL,
`login` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_user` BEFORE INSERT ON `users`
DECLARE some_var int(11) default 0;
FOR EACH ROW
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO some_var FROM users WHERE users.email=NEW.email AND 
users.login=NEW.login
IF (some_var > 0) 
    THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error for inserting login or email';
END IF;
END
```

При обработке вашего запроса были обнаружены ошибки:
Данный запрос не был выполнен: "CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_user` BEFORE INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE some_var int(11) default 0; FOR EACH ROW SELECT COUNT(*) INTO some_var FROM users WHERE users.email=NEW.email AND users.login=NEW.login IF (some_var > 0) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error for inserting login or email'; END IF; END"

Ответ MySQL:

Comment: declare до for each row, отсутствует begin. внимательней посмотрите примеры https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html  Кроме того не надо писать триггер для проверки уникальности, достаточно создать уникальный индекс из этих двух полей. P.S. хотя проверка на уникальность вместе с паролем выглядит крайне странно. получается с разными паролями может быть несколько пользователей с одним именем. такое поведение вызовет массу проблем с безопасностью

Comment: @Mike, я думаю там будет что-то типа "Вы не можете зарегистрироваться с данным паролем - он уже используется пользователем vasya". Но я могу и ошибаться.